# Is there a way to bypass "ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY" on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, diffie-hellman

I have an application which used to work fine on Chrome before the update. But since the update I keep getting this error "ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY"

I have been searching how to get rid of this error on Chrome

People have figured a way to do this on Mozilla and that's what I found on SO too. But is there a way to do it on Chrome as well.

I don't want all the unsecured websites to open in my browser, but at least my localhost. I cannot add any more ciphers to my application.

Thanks in advance.

Is there a way I can add exception for my localhost to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just add the appropriate ciphers to the domain.xml or server.xml

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
```

There was actually a solution on SO. This link might help you too..

[Diffie-Hellman public key error with Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931692/diffie-hellman-public-key-error-with-tomcat-7)